# How can pass actionlink parameter to controller MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can I pass `NextPrevious` value to controller?

Now `NextPrevious` is getting always null

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PremiumUserRegistration(PartnersVM partnersVM, string NextPrevious)
    {
        if (NextPrevious != null)
        {
        }
    }
```

View And .js file,

```js
$('.btnActionNext').click(function () {  
    $(this).closest('form')[0].submit();  
});
```

```html
@Html.ActionLink("Next >>", "PremiumUserRegistration", new { controller = "UserRegister" }, new { NextPrevious = "value", @class = "btnActionNext" , onclick = "return false;" })
```

Please help me...

Comment: where is NextPrevious populated from?

Comment: why not havenextprevious inside the partnervm. If its required in the registeation you should include that in your view model.

Comment: @ADyson , it is Action method string parameter. 'NextPrevious', it is used when click on this link button I want to get 'value' from 'NextPrevious' parameter.

Comment: I can see that. I meant where do you get the value from, which you want to pass to the server under this parameter name. Your example just provides a fixed string "value" - I assume that's not really what you want. Also, since your action method is a POST, try using [FromBody], otherwise because NextPrevious is a simple type (string, not an object), it will assume that the value is passed on the query string, not in the request body. i.e. `public ActionResult PremiumUserRegistration(PartnersVM partnersVM, [FromBody] string  NextPrevious) {`

Comment: @Luminous_Dev : Actually I have 3 tables. The table filled from 4 view forms by the way next, previous action button, then last or 4th view page there is a Save button for save whole model data. So I think that when click on each linkbuttons then pass param to controller then bind each model object to hidden fields then after save whole data from last view page.

Comment: so each view will have the model from the previous view? 1...1,2...1,2,3...1,2,3,4??

Comment: @Luminous_Dev, Yes Sir!!! Exactly... please give me Idea.. How can I ?

Comment: what does 'string nextprevious' expected to have?

Comment: not a good idea i would use asp.net session, which is like global variable per session. save the model in session and bind all together in the end

Comment: @Luminous_Dev  'nextprevious' means if the variable is not null then pass the 1st view model object to 2nd view again bind the 1st model object inside hiddenfileds.

Comment: or temporarily save as 4 individual json file and in the read and combine 4

Comment: @Luminous_Dev ... Sir I can see that session idea from by google search. But the application is also used for mobiles. So I think any other issues in future so I just avoid the session approach.

Comment: @Luminous_Dev , How can I do this 'temporarily save as 4 individual json file' ? I do not have no Idea.

Comment: session is within the server it doesnt matter which device you access this web application from. And saving file, you need to import Newtonsoft.json nuget, serialise your object and save in a path you wish to save. and when you need to read, read the file, and deserialise it into object and use it

Comment: @Luminous_Dev : Thanks for reply me. Now I can handling this task by using TEMPDATA in mvc5. Is this good or bad approach in future and now?

Comment: Im also doing project regard to multi paged form. My project has 9 sections of forms and on the 10th is a review page of whole 9 forms in one page. I am using session to temperarily storing data and backing it up as a file per user. The way I designed this is to give flexibility and availability. If suddenly browser is closed, the data is still saved until the last work. If logged in from another computer, I can look up the users file from the server and render that back in to continue work. I wouldnt use tempdata if there is another better solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a hidden:

```
<input type="hidden" name="Action" />
```

Make sure it's on your form.  Next, on your click handler, do:

```
$('.btnActionNext').click(function () {  
    $("#Action").val("NEXT");
    $(this).closest('form')[0].submit();  
});
```

In your post action, add `string Action`:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PremiumUserRegistration(string Action, PartnersVM partnersVM)
    {
        if (Action == "NEXT")
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: No need to define new route?

Comment: No since it is a post, and the Action variable comes from a standard form element, no need to define a new route.  I use this technique for similar things all of the time in my apps.

Comment: Then Action variable he can get from form collection within method . Doesn't he? Then why to use one more extra parameter?

Comment: I don't think adding one more parameter hurts either... adding another parameter doesn't hurt anything because it's a POST and MVC takes care of supplying the data anyway.  it is useful if using unit testing because you can pass a testable value in directly without mocking the HttpContext.

Comment: I am not against that but I am curious about- is it correct way to do it. Runtime will give me desired value as parameter that is beneficial. But as you say about testable, does supplying value might be supporting testability but it is not giving guaranty of success at actual runtime.

Comment: Action parameter value maps to hidden value.  If it doesn't give you a guarantee at runtime, it's because the form POST doesn't have an "Action" HTTP form field.  So guaranteed success as long as setup correctly.  I use this in my MVC action method all the time and it works great.

Comment: Did not get my point. Your test may be successful but it does not guarantee success at runtime. So does these kind of tests really serve the purpose?

Comment: Your test has to be accurate enough to mimic inputs.  If my unit tests pass in "NEXT" or "PREVIOUS", and the test passes, but the app in production doesn't do that, of course that's a problem.  The point of unit testing is to test realistically the positive and negative conditions that are within the realm of possibility.  MVC has always served up, as in my example, "NEXT" to the Action parameter of the action method.  So I don't understand why you say does not guarantee success at runtime.....  Can you provide how it might not guarantee success?

Comment: You explained it correct and clearly. My intention was to get clarity and it has come :-). Thanks.

Comment: Cool, glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

If you are submitting a form, then add it as a hidden field

```
@Html.Hidden("NextPrevious", value)
```

Otherwise, you entered the "NextPrevious" value in the wrong spot in the ActionLink method. It should be within routeValues, not htmlAttributes.
The correct way would be:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Next >>", "PremiumUserRegistration", new { controller = "UserRegister", NextPrevious = "value" }, new { @class = "btnActionNext", onclick = "return false;" })
```